# Does Twitter's changes to their public APIs affect Tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Twitter announced that Site Streams, User Streams, and legacy Direct Message endpoints, originally slated for retirement on June 19th 2018, will be deprecated on Wednesday August 16, 2018 which provides 3 months from today’s release of the Account Activity API for migration.

I am wondering it those APIs have an effect on Tweepy.Stream class

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question seems to have nothing to do with programming. Please include a clear problem description and if possible some minimal code. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @5th Tweepy is a Python Twitter library.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering it those APIs have an effect on Tweepy.Stream class

Yes. Tweepy is not a special case. On August 16, the streaming APIs will be shut off, and any code in Tweepy which interacted with them will no longer function.